# When writing a Prediction Equation, can the natural log of the dependent variable be used as a significant predictor?

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I am meant to find the the variable that accounts for the highest percentage of variance in dependent variable SalePrice. I use the following code to find that the natural log of the SalePrice had the highest r-square value of over 90%:

```
proc reg data = proj.team4;
    model SalePrice = Log_Price;
    title "Regression of SalePrice and Log_Price";
run;
```

The varaible that came in second was Overall_Qual with a r-square value of about 50%.

I must write a prediction equation that will predict the value of SalePrice given the best significant predictor. Even though the Log_price r-square is much higher, am I right to think that the Overall_Qual variable should be used in the prediction equation instead?

My reasoning being that an equation that looks like this:

SalePrice = m(ln(SalePrice)) + b

would never predict the value of SalePrice since the value of SalePrice is needed in order to carry out the equation.

Comment: This looks like a statistic question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Though this mathematically makes some sense to try and fit any function over a domain by a linear function, **this is statistical nonsense**, because it is not telling anything about what determines `SalesPrice`.